# Different tab style depending on tab item template?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a tab control with two different potential item templates:

```
<TabControl ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource tabTemplateSelector}"/>
```

Now, I also have styles for it:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                ...
```

The thing is, I want the tab item style template to be different depending on the value of `ItemTemplateSelector`. How can I do this? Basically, I don't want that entire style rule to be applied to every tab item, just the ones with a specific tab item template.

**Update:** to make it clearer, the style has `TargetType` set to `TabItem`. I want to apply that style only to those tab items that have a specific item template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ContentPresenter` in the `ControlTemplate` will display what's in the `ItemTemplate`. So you won't be able to switch the `Template` from inside the `ControlTemplate`.

Instead, you could use a `DataTrigger` to set the `Template`. The `DataTrigger` will check if the `ItemTemplate` that will be generated should have the other `Template` or not.

You will probably need a converter for this but here is an easy example. Say that your `ItemTemplateSelector` returns the other `DataTemplate` if `Name` is equal to "Tab 2". Then your `Style` with the `DataTrigger` would look like this

```
<Style TargetType="TabItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                <!-- Your first Template -->
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="Tab 2">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                        <!-- Your other Template -->
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```